# Is this 4-vector identity $k^\mu k^\nu = \frac{1}{4}k^2\delta^{\mu\nu}$ correct?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum, trace

I've often seen the identity

\begin{equation}
k^\mu k^\nu = \frac{1}{4}k^2\delta^{\mu\nu} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

used in various derivations (for example, see Schwartz QFT pg. 625). This result doesn't make any sense to me. Let's consider the simple four-vector
$$
k^\mu = (1,0,0,0)
$$
Here, $k^2 = 1$ (using mostly-minus metric). Therefore,
\begin{equation}
k^0k^0 = 1 \neq \frac{1}{4}
\quad
\text{or}
\quad
k^1k^1 = 0 \neq \frac{1}{4}
.
\end{equation}
What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rule (1) contains an implicitly written angular $k$-integration:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}\! d^{d-1}\Omega ~  k^{\mu}k^{\nu}
~=~\int_{\mathbb{S}^{d-1}}\! d^{d-1}\Omega ~   k^2 \delta^{\mu\nu}/d.\tag{1'}$$
(Schwartz is working with $d=4$ dimensions and Euclidean signature.) The rule (1) is of course not true without the angular integration/averaging in $k$-space.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510432/2451