# Why this momentum identity is true?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor, invariants

[image]
In this part has this identity and I could not understand, why factor 4, for me

$$k^{\mu}k^{\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}k²$$

Since $$k²=k_{\mu}k^{\mu}.$$

Unless the notation is the same but the product is different,Could someone explain to me why(the context is anomalous magnetic moment of electron)

Reference: M.D. Schwartz, *Quantum  Field  Theory  and  the  Standard  Model;*  page 338.

Comment: two hints: (1) it is only true in the integral.(2) in $d$ dimensions it is $k^\mu k^\nu \rightarrow d k^2 g^{\mu\nu}$ . I believe all that is explained in P&S.

Answer (score 3):

Schwartz is using the fact that under the integration sign
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\! \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d} f(k^2) k^{\mu}k^{\nu}
~=~\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\! \frac{d^dk}{(2\pi)^d} f(k^2) k^2 g^{\mu\nu}/d,$$
where $d$ is the spacetime dimension, cf. e.g. Ref. 2, [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510432/2451) related Phys.SE post, and above comment by Oбжорoв.

References:

1. M.D. Schwartz, [*QFT & the standard model*](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/), 2014; section 17.2.
2. M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, *An Intro to QFT;* eq. (6.46).