# What does 't Hooft mean by "integrating symmetrically"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, integration, self-energy

I always wanted to understand what re-normalization in particle  physics really means. Having a background in statistical  physics I do understand it in there but as far as I know re-normalization in particle physics is different; it has to do with removing infinite contributions to  series expansion terms of the scattering matrix amplitudes. In other words certain Feynman diagrams, when computed naively, are divergent and one performs some tricks to obtain finite quantities.

Now, in order to understand what  those tricks are I decided to study the paper by Gerard 't Hooft [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Src.png), a paper that supposedly earned him a Nobel prize in physics.
In chapter 2 in page 175 the author computes the so called photon self-energy, meaning a probability amplitude for a photon to create a virtual positron-electron pair that is short lived and annihilates after a while. The original integral is infinite because the integrand  grows quadratically with the momentum $k$-vector for large values of $k$.

The author replaces the electron propagator by a linear combination of similar propagators with certain constraints being imposed on the coefficients. As far as I can see those constraints have an effect that they remove those quadratic contributions to the integral at infinity  and as a result it is possible to make that integral finite. But now I got completely stuck on top of the next page  meaning in equation (2.3) which reads as follows:

[image]

In the left hand side we have an integral over the space time and on the right hand side, in addition to that integral , we have some new scalar quantity $x\in [0,1] $.
Now, my question would be twofold, firstly can anyone explain to me how this equality has been obtained? Is this an exact equality or some sort of approximation? What does the author mean by "integrating symmetrically"?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Src.png) G.'t HOOFT, Renormalization of massless Yang-Mills theories, Nuclear Physics B33 (1971) 173-199.  [https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/gthpub/massless.pdf](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ehooft101/gthpub/massless.pdf)

Comment: This is just the Feynman trick to express the inverse of the product of polynomials as an integral, any book treating QFT and renormalization introduces this. I recommend Peskin & Schroeder.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thank you very much for that. So this is nothing else but  identity (A.40) or the more generic version of it (6.42) from Peskin and Schroeder. As such that step is mathematically rigorous. But then I have problems with equations (2.6) in page 176 in the G d'Hooft paper, which are integrals of the whole k-space. Those integrals do not exist!  I guess this has something to do with results (A.44)--(A.48) in Peskin and Schroeder. Am I right?

Comment: @Przemo Yes, this is this equation in P&S. 't Hooft certainly uses something similar to (6.53) in P&S for his integrals. They are divergent, but he writes only their finite contributions.

Comment: @Przemo Note that your question is about regularisation and not about renormalisation. There is a difference !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

't Hooft means that after he has introduced the [Feynman parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization),

1. firstly, he shifts the integration variable $k^{\mu}$ so that the denominator only depends on the integration variables via the norm square $k^2$,
2. secondly, he removes the odd parts of the integrand, since he integrates over a symmetric region.

See e.g. also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510432/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thanks. I think I finally start to understand it. The bit that I was missing was that after applying the Feynman parameterization he shifts the integration variable $k  + q (1-x) \rightarrow k $ and this produces those additional $x$-dependent terms in the numerator and also the term being quadratic in $x$ in the denominator. And here the $\gamma_i$'s are the Dirac matrices because after all it is supposed to be a relativistic theory-- non-classical.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.