# Dimensional regularisation and Wick theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, dimensional-analysis, covariance, wick-rotation

Consider an integral:

$$I^{ij}=\int\frac{d^d\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^d}p^i p^j f(\textbf{p}^2).$$
How can we show that this is equal to:
$$I^{ij}=\frac{\delta^{ij}}{d}\int\frac{d^d\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^d}\textbf{p}^2 f(\textbf{p}^2).$$

My attempt is to rewrite like
$$I^{12}=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dp_1 dp_2 p_1 p_2\int\frac{d^{d-2}\textbf{p}_q}{(2\pi)^d}f(p^2_1+p^2_2+\textbf{p}^2_q)$$ where we separated the rotationally invariant parts, and probably we need to do a clever change of variable transform somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/510432/2451